# "Ideal" Solid State Switches?

Tags: led, switches, solid-state-devices

I want an LED to turn off when the input voltage falls below a certain point, e.g., 3.3V.  Originally, I was going to use a basic 2N2222 or 2N4401 transistor, however, because they act as "amplifiers" rather than ideal switches, they still allow current through at 2.5V, for example.

Is there a better (as well as inexpensive) solid state switching technology that will cut power sharply at the threshold level?

Answer (score 7):

One way is to use a comparator to compare the input against a 3.3 Volt reference.

The output of the comparator can be used to drive a BJT or MOSFET to provide the requisite current gain - or the LED can be driven directly by the comparator if a suitably high output current comparator is used.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6oLw1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Note that comparators often have a current sink output, so a pull-up resistor would be needed at the comparator output for this to work... but that is getting into specifics.*

Comment: The LM311 (a typical comparator) can sink 50mA, no transistor is needed.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Agreed. I added the transistor because removing the transistor if unnecessary would probably be simpler for the OP, compared to adding one if they select an LM139 (16 mA sink), or need high current for their LED. Do you think I should post another variant of the schematic as well, transistor-free?

Comment: No need I think, but just good for the OP to know.

Comment: Stupid question:  What's that zener diode being used for?

Comment: @KevinSoviero As a 3.3 Volt reference.

Comment: @Kevin if your 5V is accurate and stable enough you could replace the zener with a suitable resistor. With the zener you the trip point will be (more) independent of the 5V.

Answer (score 7):

You need a little positive feedback, which gives hysteresis and "snap action".

Comparators have some hysteresis built in, or Schmitt trigger logic gates.

For inexpensive, it's hard to beat [TL431](http://www.ti.com/product/tl431).  Here is a [circuit from EDN](http://www.edn.com/design/analog/4326504/Shunt-regulator-monitors-battery-voltage) that adds a transistor to the TL431 to give a little hysteresis.  This circuit happens to do exactly what you want:

[image]

Comment: Note that LED action above is opposite of what you want. Easily altered. TL431 is superb for this BUT Vref of 2.5V will limit lowest useful voltage. TLV431 has a 1.25V ref so allows lower voltages. Also has substantially lower minimim in-regulation current - which can be useful (typically about 80 uA versus about 400 uA).

Comment: ... - Circuit above would have trouble with green LED at low voltage. Data sheet says Vcathode should not go below Vref but in practice it will self limit about 1 diode drop lower. Even then with 1.25 Vref and Vc = 1.25-~0.5 = 0.75V, LED will see only 2.25V less drop in R6 when Vsupply = 3V. Red LED gives you about 1 V lower.

Comment: The LED action is what he wants: "On" above threshold == "Off" below threshold.  TLV431 is the right choice if 3V operation is desired.  I suppose you could always get more headroom by replacing the LED with another PNP.

Comment: *Some* comparators have hysteresis built in, not all.

Comment: @WarrenYoung, can you link one without?  Isn't that just a decompensated op-amp?

Comment: Ye olde LM311. See item 6 on page 12 of [this datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm311-n.pdf). It wouldn't be necessary to add the resistor if the LM311 had built-in hysteresis. [The Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator#Hysteresis) also talks about this.

Comment: @markrages - Agh - yes, LED action is what he wants (if you can get it to run :-) ). I can't imagine what I was thinking.